# How to call a function inside a Svelte component from outside the component

Tags: svelte

I have created a simple Svelte app that has an [overlay component](https://github.com/wysher/svelte-overlay/blob/master/src/components/Overlay.svelte). The code is summarized as follows and there is a REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/33956a2109714fe0875cb76b177fde24?version=3.22.2). After selecting the item from the menu, I wish to hide the menu and close the overlay. I note there is a close() function in the overlay. Can this simply be invoked with Overlay.close() from inside the  block in App.svelte? I'm used to Python, where this is trivial since there is an object reference.

```js
<script>
  import Overlay from 'svelte-overlay';
 
    const handleSelection = (event) => {
        console.log("Selected "+event.detail.id)
        //Hide Overlay and List component: Overlay.close()?
    }
</script>



<Overlay ... />
```

Answer (score 9):

If you add export to the function inside `Overlay.svelte`

```js
export function close() {
        if (openedState) toggle(false);
    }
```

and bind the `<Overlay />` component to a variable

```
<script>
  import Overlay from 'svelte-overlay';

  let overlayComp
  
</script>

<Overlay bind:this={overlayComp} />
```

It's possible to call the function from the parent with

```js
overlayComp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the close function in the div (or the Overlay) and then call it from the component (you can also use just one `on:selection` to run `handleSelection` and `close`).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-overlay#close-from-content-repl

```
<Overlay
    on:toggle={handleToggle}
    closeOnClickOutside
    zIndex={100}
    bind:isOpen={isOpen}
>
    <button slot="parent" let:toggle on:click={toggle}>Show Menu</button>
    <div slot="content" transition:fly={{ y: 5, duration: 200 }} let:close class="content">
        <List on:selection={handleSelection} on:selection={close}/>
    </div>
</Overlay>
```

A less Svelte way is to bind a variable to the component. You can then use that variable to get the close function in your `handleSelection` function and call it.

```
let cmp

...

const handleSelection = (event) => {
    console.log("Selected "+event.detail.id)
    let close = cmp.$$.ctx[14] // This is where the close function definition is. I assume 14 would be the correct index for you too, but double-check
    close()
}

...

<Overlay
  on:toggle={handleToggle}
  closeOnClickOutside
  zIndex={100}
  bind:isOpen={isOpen}
  bind:this={cmp}
  let:toggle
>
```

To be clear, I recommend the first method of calling `close`.